# Add default nodes to filter controll Devexpress

Tags: c#, devexpress

i need to know how to add patterns to the filtercontrol when the filtercontrol that opens some default parameters appear to the user
I tried as follows

```
 [C#]Open in popup window
private void Padroes(ControleCaixaFiltro _controleCaixaFiltro, PropertyInfo prop)
{
           CustomClauseNode clausula = new CustomClauseNode(_controleCaixaFiltro.Model);                
           FilterControlHelpers.ForceAdditionalParamsCount(clausula.AdditionalOperands, 1);
           clausula.Operation = ClauseType.Equals;     
           clausula.FirstOperand = new OperandProperty(prop.Name);
           clausula.ChangeElement(ElementType.Operation);
           _controleCaixaFiltro.NoPrincipal.SubNodes.Add(clausula);
}
```

the problem is that this way the nodes appear but you can not delete them by clicking the "x" side

version of devexpress is 2012

this code does not work

```
protected override ClauseNode CreateDefaultClauseNode(FilterColumn column)
    {
        ClauseNode defaultNode = base.CreateDefaultClauseNode(column);
        if (defaultNode.AdditionalOperands.Count > 0)
        {
            OperandValue rightOperand = defaultNode.AdditionalOperands[0] as OperandValue;
            if (rightOperand != null)
            {
                rightOperand.Value = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }

        return defaultNode;
    }
```